# Unknown custom element Vue - Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Not sure what happened but this stop working today in my laravel project:

App.js

```
import { SweetModal, SweetModalTab } from 'sweet-modal-vue'

Vue.component('SweetModal', SweetModal);
```

in my php file:

```
<sweet-modal ref="challengeModal"></sweet-modal>
```

It was working until I had to re install all my node modules. I know the `sweet-modal-vue` module is in my `node_modules`.

I have also tried:

```
Vue.component('sweet-modal', SweetModal);
```

and:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
     components:{
    SweetModal
      }
});
```

Comment: Your custom components are not supposed to be in your `node_modules` but rather is your asset folder. aren't they ?

Comment: My custom components are. This is a node module for a vue component : https://github.com/adeptoas/sweet-modal-vue

Comment: Is there any error when running `npm update` `npm install` ?

Comment: Not one error. And this was working but had to re install all modules and now it is not. Driving me nuts

Comment: What kind of error do you have in your console ?

Comment: `Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <sweet-modal> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in <Root>)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147316/discussion-between-packy-and-leo).

Comment: Have you tried running `php artisan optimize` lately? As well - I highly reccomend [**this Chrome extension**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) in debugging Vue issues.

Comment: Also, does the `.vue` file exist to where it can be called as a component?

Comment: @RobertDewitt I already use that plugin and have never ran `php artisan optimize`. I cleared my cache, then versioned the js, and then un versioned the js and it started working again. No idea why.

Comment: That's really wonky - but sometimes a good re-set is just the thing. Also, about `optimize` - I use it when things are showing up as undefined but they actually exist. I use it to resolve database issues, mostly.

Comment: @RobertDewitt I will take a gander for sure. And ya, it all started with uninstalling one module that messed up some of my other ones. Then a reinstall and that broke. 3 hours later I still have no idea what happened.

Comment: I had this one project where there were so many database issues and other problems - but I moved on to other parts of development and I removed this one unused package and ran `optimize` - and it fixed 99% of the errors I had already moved on from. So weird, but satisfying all at once.